# Prisma Many To Many multiple update

Tags: many-to-many, prisma, prisma2

I have a problem with the Prisma ORM.
I have a Many To Many relation, this is the structure :

```
  id                       Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
  last_name                String               @db.VarChar(255)
  first_name               String               @db.VarChar(255)
...
  report            report_author[]
...
}
model report {
  id            Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  type          Int
  content       String          @db.LongText
  appreciation  String?         @db.VarChar(255)
  meeting_id    Int
  meeting       meeting         @relation(fields: [meeting_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, map: "report_ibfk_1")
  users report_author[]

  @@index([meeting_id], map: "report_ibfk_1")
}

model report_author {
  id        Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  report_id Int
  author_id Int
  user      user   @relation(fields: [author_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, map: "report_author_ibfk_1")
  report    report @relation(fields: [report_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, map: "report_author_ibfk_2")

  @@index([report_id], map: "report_author_ibfk_1")
  @@index([author_id], map: "report_author_ibfk_2")
}
```

Well, there is no problem about it ! My goal is to **CONNECT** an array of **USERS** who gonna be linked in my request. To be clear, my sended object will be like:

```
    id: 2,
    type: 2,
    content: '<p>I love it !</p>',
    appreciation: 'Favorable',
    meeting_id: 13,
    report_author: [{report_id:2, author_id:70},{report_id:2, author_id:70}]
```

But sometimes, in this array:
**report_author: [{report_id:2, author_id:70},{report_id:2, author_id:70}]** I will have 3,4 maybe 5 object.

**My question is :**
How can I insert (link) a variable number of user to a REPORT thanks to prisma update, upsert, connect or any query ?

Thank you !

Comment: Could you clarify if the ```user``` and ```report``` records already exist in the database? In the example, you provided, which one of the following is true: 1. Both the ```report``` with ```id``` 2 and ```user``` with ```id``` 70 already exist in the database. You simply need to connect them.  OR  2.  ```user``` with ```id``` 70 exists in the database but  ```report``` with ```id``` 2 needs to be created first and then connected with ```user```.

Comment: Okay, sorry ! So, I'll always have at least one USER and at least one REPORT in the database but my question is how to connect them if I have multiple USERS to connect to only one REPORT, I've tried to pass my users with an array like in my initial question. But it doesn't work...
I will try again from the beginning tomorrow. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: So basically, you need to use the [connect API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#connect-an-existing-record)  if you want to create a  ```report``` and connect it to existing ```user```s (as many as you like). If the ```report``` and the list of ```user``` records already exists, you can use a ```createMany``` to directly create the ```report_author``` records (you have to mention the ```report_id``` and ```author_id```.  Could you take a look if these solve your problem? If not could you please provide some code for what query you have tried?